# C++ delegate constructor with some work done beforehand

Tags: c++, constructor, constructor-chaining

I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```
class A {
    A();
    A(int num);
}

A::A()
{
    int i = /* Something that loads something */
    A(i);
}

A::A(int num)
{
    /* something involving num */   
}
```

I am aware of delegated constructors in C++ 11, what I am wondering is if it's possible to do something before invoking the delegated constructor.

Also, unrelated, but is `this` available in an initializer list?

Comment: You can compute `i` in a function and do `A() : A(foo())`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that was the answer, if you post it as the answer I'll accept.

Comment: I don't mind you accepting Richard's answer, he even mentioned another good approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some alternatives:

Default argument:

```
struct A { 
  explicit A(int i = load_something());
};
```

Deferred constructor:

```
struct A { 
  explicit A(int i);
  A() : A(load_something()) {}
};
```

Comment: Note that the 2 choicess are different in regard to `explicit`. `A()` is explicit in one case, and not for the other.

Comment: Be careful if `load_something` is a virtual method of `A` (or a base class of `A`).